# How to find newly deployed tokens on Solana?

Tags: token, deploy, liquiditypool

I’m trying to find how I can see token contracts as they are being deployed on Solana. I can find them after liquidity has been added but preferably I’d like to know how to find them before the liquidity is added. Just can’t see where I can see newly deployed tokens. Thanks

Comment: How do you find them when Liquidity has been added? I am still learning the SOL ecosystem myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the token program directly and filter for initialize mint instructions. Check out Webhooks on one of the RPC providers such as Helius for a way to do this very quickly. https://docs.helius.dev/webhooks-and-websockets/quick-start